# Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' after upgrade to macOS Big Sur

Tags: flutter, dart, build.gradle, macos-big-sur, build-error

Last week I managed to upgrade from Catalina to Big Sur. I hope you have some ideas to help me with my problem. Thanks in advance.

I have a Flutter project that I've been maintaining for months that worked on both Android and iOS before the update. We share the project via GIT and everything works for the other three in the team. Now, unfortunately, I get BUILD FAILED on both Android and iOS.

When I got the errors after upgrading to Big Sur, I also decided to update all Flutter components.

One thing up front. When I start a new Flutter project, I can build it in both Android and iOS. So it's not a fundamental problem.

**Setup**

- MacBook Pro 2019, macOS 11.2.2 (current version)
- VS Code 1.54.1 (current version)

**Flutter Doctor**

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on macOS 11.2.2 20D80 darwin-x64, locale
    de-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

**Android Error**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/delegate_widget.dart:194:18: Error: Superclass has no method named 'inheritFromElement'.
    return super.inheritFromElement(ancestor, aspect: aspect);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:259:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.

 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider<T>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:260:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.

        : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/eds/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/eds/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

**iOS build error in VS Code**

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

**iOS build error in Xcode**

```
...

    export variant\=normal
    /bin/sh -c /Users/eds/Downloads/rinoko/rinoko/build/ios/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh

../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/delegate_widget.dart:194:18: Error: Superclass has no method named 'inheritFromElement'.
    return super.inheritFromElement(ancestor, aspect: aspect);
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:259:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as InheritedProvider<T>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-3.2.0/lib/src/provider.dart:260:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('../../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
        : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

**What I have already tried**

- updating all componentes (maybe not a good idea?)
- flutter clean
- cleaning all DerivedData (Xcode)
- git reset --hard origin/master

**A few ideas**

- Could the Big Sur update have changed any read and write permissions?
- Does it make sense to delete and reinstall all components again? But actually the new Flutter projects work.

If you need more stacktraces etc. please let me know as well.
I hope you have some ideas.
Greetings and thanks

Comment: Hey, edstrinova. I had a similar problem just recently, and I fixed it through updating the version of the flutter provider package in my pubspec.yaml file.  In my case, reinstalling the flutter sdk didn't work.  Here is the link to the latest version of the provider package - https://pub.dev/packages/provider/install

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the .env file was missing.
After I included that file, it was working.

Other solutions may be :

- Delete pubspec.lock file and run flutter pub get, then run the app.
- Remove the .gradle folder inside of C:\ and then build the app.

Comment: Deleting pubspec.lock file worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every solution that is suggested here. However, I solved it by just renaming the google-services.json file. Because I have two copies of the google-services.json file, the file appeared on my project as (google-services(1).json). So I had to rename it to be (goole-services.json).